# Enormous file cannot be uploaded

Tags: php, curl, file-upload

I have the following script:

```
<?php

var_dump($_FILES);
?>
```

And I try via curl to upload a file:

```
curl -X POST -c ~/cookies.txt -b ~/cookies.txt -F "excell=@/home/pcmagas/Έγγραφα/Job/Kosmima/Είδη με Φωτογραφίες.xls" http://localhost/uploadstest.php ; echo
```

But all I get is an empty array.

And I cannot figure out why. Maybe is because the file I am uploading is 56,2Mbytes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed to add the following lines on my .htaccess:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 250M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```